# how to reload a gif in swift UIWebView

Tags: swift, uiwebview

/* I am trying to reload a gif in `UIwebView` in swift but I have no idea how to reload the gif in a continuous loop . Load request doesn't work and not even `reload()` */

Let

```
filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("alienImage", ofType: "gif")

    let gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

    let webViewBG = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)

    webViewBG.loadData(gif!, MIMEType: "image/gif",textEncodingName: String(), baseURL: NSURL())

    webViewBG.userInteractionEnabled = false;

    self.view.addSubview(webViewBG)
```

Comment: If your purpose is just showing GIF images, please consider using FLAnimatedImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSTimer` for that like shown into below code:

```
myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("myPerformeCode:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And helper method will be:

```
func myPerformeCode(timer : NSTimer) {

    count++

    if count < totalCount {
        let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("\(count)", ofType: "gif")
        let gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
        self.webView.loadData(gif!, MIMEType: "image/gif",textEncodingName: String(), baseURL: NSURL())
        self.webView.userInteractionEnabled = false
    } else {
        count = 1
    }
}
```

Complete code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    let totalCount = 61
    var count = 1
    var myTimer = NSTimer()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {

        myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("myPerformeCode:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func myPerformeCode(timer : NSTimer) {

        print("Called")
        count++

        if count < totalCount {
            let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("\(count)", ofType: "gif")
            let gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
            self.webView.loadData(gif!, MIMEType: "image/gif",textEncodingName: String(), baseURL: NSURL())
            self.webView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        } else {
            count = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

After that you can remove timer with `myTimer.invalidate()` whenever you are switching views.